# IOS UIButton (DLRadioButton) height doesn't depend on title label text size

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, storyboard

I have 3 radio buttons DLRadioButton(UIButton inheritor). 
They are located one under the other.

[image]

I want buttons height to increase is title label height increases. I set number of lines = 0:

```
    btn1.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    btn2.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    btn3.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

to get as many rows as I need. But it works only up to 2 rows. If text size is big, button height doesn't increase and labels overlap.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: did you set a height constraints for the Buttons or embedding them into a fixed height stackView ??

Comment: To use that [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) library, you will need to either give your radio buttons explicit heights, or edit the source code to return an `intrinsicContentSize` based on the auto-layout resulting `titleLabel` size.

Comment: @DonMag I tried this:

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
        var btnSize = self.titleLabel!.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: 10000))
        btnSize.width = super.intrinsicContentSize.width
        return btnSize
    }


But it doesn't work. I think sizeThatFits returns height less than height of. the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the source for the `DLRadioButton` class.

Here is a quick example change.

Note: this change will only work for left-icon position with multi-line button labels. Right-icon position will still work with single-line buttons.

In `DLRadioButton.m` in the library source, add this method:

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
    CGSize sz = self.titleLabel.bounds.size;
    sz.height += self.titleEdgeInsets.top + self.titleEdgeInsets.bottom;
    sz.width += self.icon.size.width + self.titleEdgeInsets.left + self.titleEdgeInsets.right + self.marginWidth;
    return sz;
}
```

You can then lay out your buttons like this (or generate them from code, doesn't matter):

[image]

and sample Swift view controller code:

```
class MultilineViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var qTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var button1: DLRadioButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: DLRadioButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: DLRadioButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for btn in [button1, button2, button3] {
            btn?.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        }
    }

}
```

For this result (I just added another VC to the example app's tab bar):

[image]

The "radio button circle" will be positioned vertically-centered. If you wanted it to be aligned with the top line of text, that would need some additional editing.

If you're not looking to use the other features of this `DLRadioButton` library (such as icon images, right-icon positioning, multi-select checkbox groups, etc), you may want to look at other implementations (lots of them out there) or write your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer.  I solved this issue:
let lbl = UILabel()
lbl.numberOfLines = 0
lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12) // make sure you set this correctly 
lbl.text = "My text that may or may not wrap lines..."

let width = 100.0 // the width of the view you are constraint to, keep in mind any applied margins here

let height = lbl.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: width, height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel).height

Is this way correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
import DLRadioButton

class CustomDLRadioButton: DLRadioButton {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        if let label = self.titleLabel {
            label.sizeToFit()
            var sz = label.bounds.size;
            sz.height += self.titleEdgeInsets.top + self.titleEdgeInsets.bottom
            sz.width += self.icon.size.width + self.titleEdgeInsets.left + self.titleEdgeInsets.right + self.marginWidth
            return sz
        }
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}

let button = CustomDLRadioButton()
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

This is a Swift version of the accepted answer. You can subclass DLRadioButton method and override intrinsicContentSize property, it works for me.